# How do I make a my bootstrap sub-menu visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the following html, I hide the sub-menu using the CSS that follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-menu">
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item drop">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index-2.html">Home 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index-3.html">Home 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS to hide sub menu:

```
.main-menu li.drop ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

To make the sub menu visible when it is hovered, I use the following CSS but it is not working:

```
.main-menu li.drop a:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have jQuery installed in your project? I should be able to solve the problem using jQuery as I have identified the issue.